# How to make a pictogram / icon chart?

Tags: python, charts, data-visualization, pie-chart, waffle-chart

*Is there a method to produce a pictogram-chart with python* (be it with matplotlib, seaborn, ggplot, etc.)*?* — I am not sure, which term is the most standard-term for this type of graphs, maybe also: square pie chart, pictograph, icon chart, picture chart, pictorial unit chart. `R` has the package [waffle](https://github.com/hrbrmstr/waffle) for this. What I mean is something like this:

apples (11): `OOOOOOOOOOO`

pencils (3): `/ / /`

This type of charts was a fundamental method for Otto Neurath. But how can I plot such a chart with python?

Comment: A pictorgram chart is somewhat similar to a barplot, so I'd look at the functionality in each of those modules and see if any of them support the kind of customization you'd need to get them to produce the former. If not, then maybe you can add it yourself (if they're open-source).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [PyWaffle python package](https://pypi.org/project/pywaffle/) ([available on github](https://github.com/ligyxy/PyWaffle) or via 'pip install pywaffle' [from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pywaffle/)) which leverages matplotlib to create waffle plots.